# MongoDB Determine allocation strategy of existing collection

Tags: mongodb

How do I determine the allocation strategy for an existing collection? UsePowerOf2 vs Exact size. I know that Power of 2 is the new default but I need to determine for an existing collection, how would I verify what it is using since it could be either depending on when / how the collection was created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Doc of [`callMod`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/collMod/#dbcmd.collMod):

> Use the [`userFlags`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/collStats/#collStats.userFlags) field in the [`db.collection.stats()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.stats/#db.collection.stats) output to check enabled collection flags.

so you have to call.

```
db.collectionName.stats()
```

and look at the key `userFlags`.

From the Doc of [`userFlags`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/collStats/#collStats.userFlags)

> collStats.userFlags New in version 2.2.
>
> Reports the flags on this collection set by the user. In version 2.2
>   the only user flag is usePowerOf2Sizes. If usePowerOf2Sizes is
>   enabled, userFlags will be set to 1, otherwise userFlags will be 0.
>
> See the collMod command for more information on setting user flags and
>   usePowerOf2Sizes.